# `fancyhdr` and automatic line length

Tags: header-footer, fancyhdr, automation

I want to create a template for notes and I was thinking to use `fancyhdr` package. So far I face two problems:

[1] I don't want the header in the first page, but only the footer

[2] I would like to have a line---centered, that is it does not appear as an underline---in the middle of header and footer the length of which can be automatically adjusted given the entries on the far left and right. This line should not touch the left an right entries.

I shall provide a minimal example.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fancybox}

\usepackage{lastpage}
 \usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage[left=2.5cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}  


\lhead{Notes on ABC}
\chead{\line(1,0){200}} 
\rhead{\textit{\textcopyright \, Author, \the\year}}   
\lfoot{Chapter 1: A brief introduction in }
\cfoot{\line(1,0){200}}       
\rfoot{Page \thepage \hspace{1pt} of \pageref{LastPage}}

%  Defining the vertical distance in enumeration and itemization
 \usepackage{enumitem}
 \setlist{itemsep=2pt,parsep=2pt,topsep=15pt}


\begin{document}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\vspace{2cm}

\Ovalbox{
\begin{minipage}{0.85\textwidth}
\begin{center}
{\normalsize Notes in ... \\ 
Do not distribute without author's approval.
}
\end{center}
\end{minipage}
}

\vspace{4cm}

\begin{center}
{\Huge \textbf{Chapter 1}} \\ 
{\LARGE \textbf{A Brief Introduction in ... }}
\end{center}

\vspace{0.25cm}

\section{The origins}

\par \lipsum 

\newpage

\section{Another section}

\par Something ...

\end{document}
```

Comment: Why aren't you using e.g. `\title` and `\maketitle` and a class which supports `\chapter{}`? Your document ought not include explicit markup like that.

Comment: I am not sure that you can use something before `\chapter` and if you can have footer in the same page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sets things up to use semantic markup in the document e.g. `\title`, `\chapter` etc. It patches `\chapter` so that it does not start a new page and uses the `report` class with no title page. Note that your title is off-centre. Assuming that is deliberate, I've emulated it here. I've substituted `pagelts` for `lastpage` since `lastpage` has been issuing warnings telling you to do this for ages. (I know because I ignored them until things wouldn't compile, too.) I've also adjusted `headheight` because `fancyhdr` is complaining that your page layout will be inconsistent (and it is changing the value anyway whether you like it or not).

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,notitlepage]{report}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fancybox}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{pageslts}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{titling}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage[left=2.5cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm, headheight=14pt]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{xhfill}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\usepackage{lipsum}



\fancyhf{}
\chead{\parbox{\textwidth}{\thetitle\ \hrulefill\ \textit{\textcopyright\ \theauthor, \the\year}}}
\cfoot{\parbox{\textwidth}{\nouppercase{\leftmark}\ \xrfill[1ex]{.4pt}\ Page \thepage\ of \pageref{LastPage}}}

\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
  \fancyhf{}%
  \cfoot{\parbox{\textwidth}{\nouppercase{\leftmark}\ \xrfill[1ex]{.4pt}\ Page \thepage\ of \pageref{LastPage}}}}

%  Defining the vertical distance in enumeration and itemization
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist{itemsep=2pt,parsep=2pt,topsep=15pt}

\pretitle{%
  \vskip 20mm
  \begin{Sbox}%
    \begin{minipage}{.85\textwidth}% off-centre title ??
      \begin{center}%
        \normalsize}
\posttitle{%
      \par
      \end{center}%
    \end{minipage}%
  \end{Sbox}\Ovalbox{\TheSbox}%
  \vskip .5em}
\title{Notes in \dots\\Do not distribute without author's approval.}
\date{}
\author{}

\makeatletter
  \renewcommand \thesection {\@arabic\c@section}
\makeatother

\patchcmd{\chapter}{\clearpage}{\relax}{}{}
\patchcmd{\chapter}{\cleardoublepage}{\relax}{}{}

\begin{document}
  \pagenumbering{arabic}
  \pagestyle{fancy}
  \maketitle\thispagestyle{plain}
  \author{Author}
  \title{Notes on ABC}

  \chapter{A Brief Introduction in \dots }

  \section{The origins}

  \lipsum

  \newpage

  \section{Another section}

  Something ...

\end{document}
```

I've emulated some, but not all of your formatting. You may wish to change the format of chapters, for example. If so, there are plenty of questions on that topic. The main thing is to do this stuff in your preamble and ***not*** to include explicit markup in the document itself.

[image: first two pages]

Comment: Thank you very much for your help and effort! I have a question. Can this code, somehow, be altered so that the header does not appear in the first page and the line (in both header and footer) to be located in the middle (aka centered in the middle of an imaginary box)? Now it seems as it underlines something.

Comment: @PantelisKazakis The header does not appear on the first page. (There was an error in my initial post but I corrected it 2 minutes later so it does not show an 'edit'.) I'm not sure what you mean about the centring. You said it should adjust to the lengths of the stuff on each side. So obviously it will not be horizontally centred. Or do you mean vertically centred?

Comment: cfr, thanks. I reloaded the code and now it works in terms of the header in the first page. What I meant about the line is this: go for example in the first page and you will see that the line is at the very bottom of the letter P (where it say Page 1 of 3). I was asking whether this line can be in about the center of this letter (and as a consequence all other letters).

Comment: @PantelisKazakis See my edit. There is (naturally!) a package for this, too. the optional argument to `\xrfill` specifies how much to raise the line above the baseline. The mandatory argument specifies the height of the rule. (I think `.4pt` matches the default but I'm not certain.) Adjust and enjoy ;).

Comment: @PantelisKazakis Do consider up-voting or accepting my answer if it provides a satisfactory solution! (But obviously wait if you want to see if a better answer comes along.)

Comment: cfr, I am much obliged :) Have a nice day!